# How to save multiple .mat file in image format

Tags: image, matlab

I'm trying to save all mat files, which are basically 2D image data, in jpg image format. But there is a problem in saving in jpg format. Only last file saved- problem is in updating the file name.

Output should be

```
XZ1.jpg
XZ2.jpg
XZ3.jpg
.
.
.
XZ300.jpg
```

Would you check where am i wrong, but its ok for .mat file saving.

```
for i = 1:300 

   data = Y(:,:,i);   % Z-X planes 

   % save as mat file 

   currentFile = sprintf('XZ%d.mat', i);

   save(currentFile,'data') % to save as mat file


   % save as jpg

   currentFile = sprintf('Slice%d.jpg', i);

   imwrite(data, 'currentFile.jpg')

   end
```

Comment: Look closely at your `imwrite` call. You are not using your `currentFile` variable.

Comment: sorry, I also tried for imwrite(data, 'currentFile') but not working @ excaza

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not working"? Are you getting errors? Is the output not what you expect?

Comment: i got only one image not all 300 image, would you suggest me another function to save mat as image.

Comment: It is `imwrite(data, currentFile)`, not `imwrite(data, 'currentFile')`

Comment: thanks @Daniel, loop is working well now as per your suggestion. But the saved jpg images do not carry info what the mat file has. The mat file is a 104*281 unit8 matrix having binary data (0,1). There should be a white circle in the saved image but its all black. I checked the 104*281 matrix from workspace. all centre region of this matrix has pixel value 1.   is there any problem with imwrite function.  would yo help me where is the problem

Comment: I think the range should be `[0, 255]`, so if you multiply `data = data * 255;`, you should get the colors right!

Comment: Thanks @Lisa, its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the output "The required output" should be
Slice1.jpg 
Slice2.jpg

right now the output is :  currentFile.jpg

and this contains the last slice of data data = Y(:,:,300);

when you run the code the code use the same file name each loop to save the JPEG file.

change the line imwrite(data, 'currentFile.jpg') to 
imwrite(data, currentFile)  will solve the problem

But: remember that JPEG is a loss compression standard.
In other words if you read the file again the data will not be exactly the same.
if your data is a high frequency data you will lose a lot of information